# metronome in C# for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am a total newbie for app development with a *little* knowledge of c#. I have some free time in my hand ans was thinking of learning WP7 app development as well as c#. So, I figured I will build a metronome app in c# for WP7. I think learning by doing a project will me most effective.

But, I haven't been able to find much resources on how to accomplish this. On the web there are lots of tuts on how to build a metronome in JS but not in c#. So, If anyone can  point me to some resources to get me started, that would be great. I'll be trying hard learning bits by bits as I progress.

Comment: Your question is very vague and is likely to be closed. What have you tried so far? And what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3):

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/ You will find tutorials, videos & all sorts of other excellent good times on here.